# How would the SQL server optimize sum of constants

Tags: sql-server

```
create function dbo.GetAPlusB
returns int
as
begin
    declare @a int = 2
    declare @b int = 2

    return @a + @b
end
```

Will the SQL server optimize such a function into something like this? (or even inline the constant where the function is called)

```
create function dbo.GetAPlusB
returns int
as
begin
    return 4
end
```

Comment: This seems like overly simplified example. Why would you ever have a function like that in the first place? No, SQL Server wouldn't "shortcut" it, but the whole idea is nonsensical. Why would you have a function with no parameters to add the values `2` and `2` together at all? We all know the answer is `4`, and using a multi-line scalar function is a waste of overhead.

Comment: Of course the example is simplified. In the real function there are 3 constants (bit flags) that are combined with each other with help of binary OR. It's done so, because otherwise the constant seems not human friendly at all.

Comment: Why not show us your *real* function then, and then ask about that? Overly simplified examples won't give you the answer you're after.

Comment: The question is about optimization, and the synthetic example clearly illustrates the subject. In this specific case posting the real function won't add anything meaningful.

Comment: OK, Larnu, should you need a constant for several of your SPs, how would you define it in SQL?

Comment: I'm not sure what that has to do with the question you've asked . If you have a new question, you should be posting a new question.

Comment: Consider function GetAPlusB as just a way to define a constant (4) that is shared between several SPs. The goal is to do not hardcode 4 in several places.

Comment: Regarding inlining, I found this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining . The unanswered part is about optimization of 2 + 2 to 4 during UDF compilation.

Comment: Inlining for Scalar function is only in 2019; and the function we have here is not inline. *"The unanswered part is about optimization of 2 + 2 to 4 during UDF compilation."* I answered that in my opening comment. As for your prior comment, a function seems the wrong place if the value is subject the change it should be in a table, as users won't need the ability to amend the DDL of an object to change it. If it's not subject to change, then hard code it; as it's not going to change.

Comment: As an example, an inline function would be like this: [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019l&fiddle=6746f4f85b2eb7be52ffd6a0773b0489)